# How to get different languages for current location?

Tags: android, google-maps, reverse-geocoding, street-address

How to get current location in different language.Do we need to add some libraries?I need to find the current address in arabic language? I think there is google maps in arabic format.Similarily is there any way to get current address in arabic lamguage??

```
public static final String GOOGLE_GEOCODER = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=";

public static String getAddressFromGPSData(double lat, double longi) {
    HttpRetriever agent = new HttpRetriever();
    String request = GOOGLE_GEOCODER + lat + ","
            + longi + "&sensor=true";
    // Log.d("GeoCoder", request);
    String response = agent.retrieve(request);
    String formattedAddress = "";
    if (response != null) {
        Log.d("GeoCoder", response);
        try {
            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray arrayOfAddressResults = parentObject
                    .getJSONArray("results");
            JSONObject addressItem = arrayOfAddressResults.getJSONObject(0);
            formattedAddress = addressItem.getString("formatted_address");
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // Log.d("GeoCoder", response);
    return formattedAddress;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to "[Localize](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html)" the Map.

for example:

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("ja"));
```

will show Japanese.

It may or may not be possible to do it for Arabic. [List](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#lfields) doesn't mention it as a supported language.

Comment: i want formatted address in arabic language...in this google api [link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=8.558419,76.881584&sensor=true&language=ar)

Comment: Yes It does support arabic Locale.setDefault(new Locale("ar"));